# in react-paginate package what is the purpose of herfBuilder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, href, react-paginate

```
               <ReactPaginate
                hrefBuilder={(currentPage) => { <a href={currentPage}>hello</a> }}
                previousLabel={"previous"}
                nextLabel={"next"}
                breakLabel={"..."}
                pageCount={pageCount}
                marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                pageRangeDisplayed={3}
                onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center my-5 "}
                pageClassName={"page-item"}
                pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                previousClassName={"page-item"}
                previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                nextClassName={"page-item"}
                nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                breakClassName={"page-item"}
                breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
                activeClassName={"active"}
            />
```

acctully  i  want  to  make a  new link every  time  when i  click  the  new page button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of hrefBuilder in react-paginatino should be a function returning link for you pagination items. Thus, no need to return the a tag.

For example in your case it should be

```
<ReactPaginate
            hrefBuilder={(currentPage) => `/your/links/${currentPage}`}
            previousLabel={"previous"}
            nextLabel={"next"}
            breakLabel={"..."}
            pageCount={pageCount}
            marginPagesDisplayed={2}
            pageRangeDisplayed={3}
            onPageChange={handlePageClick}
            containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center my-5 "}
            pageClassName={"page-item"}
            pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            previousClassName={"page-item"}
            previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            nextClassName={"page-item"}
            nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            breakClassName={"page-item"}
            breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            activeClassName={"active"}
        />
```